# getBoundingClientRect() returning 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**SectionX should display the same values as the second console.log. You can see that when i log
props and sectionRef.current, i get the same values... But sectionRef.current comes with a (flex).**

```
const horizontalScroll = (props) => {
    var container = document.getElementById(styles["a-text__box"]);
    var sectionX = props.getBoundingClientRect().x;
    console.log(sectionX);
    console.log(sectionRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().x);

    console.log(props);
    console.log(sectionRef.current);

    // container.scrollTo({
    //   top: 0,
    //   left: sectionX,
    //   behavior: "smooth",
    // });
  };
```

CONSOLE:

```
  0
  1193.28125
  
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>(flex)
```

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Right now we have no way of knowing what `props` actually is.

Comment: Props receives an ref.current. In this case it receives sectionRef.current. You can see that in the logs

Comment: All we can see in the logs is that it probably points at a `div` of some sort, not which div, or where it's positioned on the page. (`props` could even just be the string `"<div>...</div>"`, from what we can see here)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.